# Combine ucwords and substr in php

Tags: php

The following echo is currently all uppercase, how do I force the first letter capitalized and the rest lower case of each word but still limit the length using substr or something similar?

```
<?php echo substr($row['fulladdress'],0,20); ?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you mean like echoing string of `"LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET"` to `"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Si"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should do it.  Just wrap it in ucfirst function

```
<?php echo ucfirst(strtolower(substr($row['fulladdress'],0,20))); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `ucfirst()` and `strtolower()`

```
<?php echo substr(ucfirst(strtolower($row['fulladdress'])),0,20); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like: `<?php echo ucfirst(strtolower(substr($row['fulladdress'],0,20))); ?>`